# How to disable to Call Alert while make call in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

How to disable to Call Alert while making call from iPhone?. Programmatically if you call to a number, iPhone ask us confirmation alert before dialing the number. How to avoid this alert message from iPhone App?

Comment: I think we cannot do that. Without user permission the os wont allow to make a call or send a message.

Comment: Dail: accessno [time gap] pin number [time gap] and phone number, every time if i use tel: command whether it will work?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible and it's perfectly ok with users. This (call, sms, ...) costs money and Apple is trying to protect users. And I personally agree with them on this point ;-)